# How to retrieve a specific field of data in parent key from child key in sqlite3 python?

Tags: python, sqlite

How to retrieve a specific field of data in parent key from child key in sqlite3 python?

```
CREATE TABLE artist(
artistid    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
artistname  TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE track(
trackid     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
trackname   TEXT, 
artistid INTEGER
FOREIGN KEY(artistid) REFERENCES artist(artistid)
);

track.execute('''SELECT artisid, trackname FROM track WHERE artistid = 1''')
```

So assume now I have executed the track table and I got the artisid and trackname, and I want to retrieve the artisname as well and put it in between, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the artist ID, you can just do a simple `SELECT`:

```
SELECT artistname FROM artist WHERE artistid = ?
```

If you want to retrieve the name in the same query, you have to join the two tables:

```
SELECT artist.artistid,
       artist.artistname,
       track.trackname
FROM track JOIN artist ON track.artistid = artist.artistid
WHERE artist.artistid = ?
```